# Typical zero sequence data for 80MVA transformer

Tags: transformer, power-engineering

I need to model a 80MVA transformer 132/33kV built in 1973. There is very little information on this transformer but I need to populate certain values in the model.

Where can I find typical zero sequence impedance values for this type of transformer?

The positive sequence impedances are as follows:

- HV – MV  = 15%
- HV – LV   =  22.9%
- MV – LV  =  4.9%

Here is the information given:

[image: Specs]

And the fields which need to be populated:

[image: Values]

Comment: A reasonable assumption is that Z0 is about 85% of Z1.

Comment: On further inspection, this appears to be a wye-wye transformer with buried delta tertiary. The above comment I made a year ago isn't really accurate for this case. Try reading some of the references I have cited in http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/195239/what-is-the-zero-sequence-equivalent-of-a-yny0-transformer/195317#195317 .

Answer (score 1):

usually the 132/33kv transformers have a Y / D connection and th LV side is resistance grounded through zig-zag transformer and so they have a moderate zero sequense impedance.
but some tests show that,

> The zero-sequence impedance is usually given as a percentage of the rated phase impedance.
>
> When the transformer has a three-limb core and no delta-connecter windings, the zero-sequence impedance is about 30...60 %. When the transformer has a delta-connected winding, the zero-sequence impedance is 0.8...1.0 times the corresponding short-circuit impedance (uk%).

(from [Testing of Power Transformer – Measurement of Zero-Sequence Impedance](http://electrical-engineering-portal.com/testing-of-power-transformer-measurement-of-zero-sequence-impedance))